# asp.net how to set up the route to get part of the url as a parameter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following route:

```
Routes.MapRoute(
    name: "go",
    template: "{controller=Go}/{action=Go}/{*Data}");
```

and I would like it to call my controller on urls like this:

> /go/somedatahere

where I could recover the *somedatahere* string

but this doesn't call the controller.

if I use:

> /go
>
> /go?something

then the controller gets called

Comment: What is the name of parameter of controller action ? You don't need * in front for Data in route configuration

Comment: Even if I remove the *, it doesn't work. I have public class GoController : Controller / public IActionResult Go(string Data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to your route

```
 template: "{controller=Go}/{action=Go}/{*Data}")
```

means the `URL` will be `go/go/mydatahere` and it will get called when you use `/go` because it will match the name of the controller of your route `{controller=Go}/{action=Go}` means when you type `/go` it will know you are talking about `Go Controller` and `Go action` so it will redirect you to `go/go` so it should be

```
 routes.MapRoute(
          name: "go",
          template: "go/{*Data}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Go", action = "Go" });
```

now `/go/somedatahere` will match the template of the route and and anything after `/go/` will be considered as `Data`